# Query to compare a range of sizes from 2 columns in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple database table that has the following columns:

```
+-------+------+-------+-------+
|Product|Brand |minSize|maxSize|
+-------+------+-------+-------+
|Prod1  |Brand1|50     |52     |
+-------+------+-------+-------+
|Prod2  |Brand2|50     |51     |
+-------+------+-------+-------+
|Prod3  |Brand3|45     |50     |
+-------+------+-------+-------+
```

A user chooses a product from a list then the database is queried for similar products based on the minSize and maxSize.

If a user chose Prod1, the database table would be queried by the selected minSize and maxSize and the results in the example data above would include Prod2, and Prod3.

I'm struggling to work out that the query find products in the allowed range. Can anyone point me in the right direction or give me an example? My SQL knowledge is limited.

Shaun

Comment: What is the criteria for including  results? In what sense are they 'similar'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the idea that you want products that have overlapping sizes.  You can do this with a `join`:

```
select pb2.*
from productbrand pb join
     productbrand pb2
     on pb.product = 'Prod1' and
        pb2.product <> pb.product and
        pb2.minsize <= pb.maxsize and
        pb2.maxsize >= pb.minsize;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon that looks like it will do the trick. Many thanks. Shaun